# Why errorlevel is still 0

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I am trying to query each instance on my CMS. But why the errorlevel is still 0 when I tested the stopped instance? And how can I skip the last line in my Instance_list.txt (The %%a will be '(44')

```
:Start
REM get the full list of our instance from CMS to Instance_list.txt
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd" -S cms_instance -e -d msdb -Q "SELECT DISTINCT server_name FROM sysmanagement_shared_registered_servers_internal" -o Instance_list.txt 
:Run
REM Run query against all instances one by one.
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2 skip=3" %%a in (Instance_list.txt) do (
Set Intance_NAME=%%a

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd" -S !Intance_NAME! -e -d master -Q "SELECT @@SERVERNAME" -o SQL_result.txt
TIMEOUT /T 2
FINDSTR "!Intance_NAME!" SQL_result.txt
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
ECHO SQL INSTANCE !Intance_NAME! HAS SOME ISSUE...
)
)
```

Comment: You seem to realize that you need to use delayed expansion for your other variables.  Why aren't you using it for the errorlevel variable?

Comment: Although `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (` will be true if `errorlevel` is 1 *or greater than 1* - based on the *current* (run-time) ERRORLEVEL value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a SQLCMD FAQ.  You need to set the -b switch for sqlcmd to set the ERRORLEVEL

> -b Specifies that sqlcmd exits and returns a DOS ERRORLEVEL value when an error occurs. The value that is returned to the DOS ERRORLEVEL
>   variable is 1 when the SQL Server error message has a severity level
>   greater than 10; otherwise, the value returned is 0. If the -V option
>   has been set in addition to -b, sqlcmd will not report an error if the
>   severity level is lower than the values set using -V. Command prompt
>   batch files can test the value of ERRORLEVEL and handle the error
>   appropriately. sqlcmd does not report errors for severity level 10
>   (informational messages).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for your replying. I added -b into my SQLCMD and skip my findstr step, but it doesn't work. BTW: I use -o to output the result of my SQLCMD query (It 's just SELECT @@SERVERNAME, very sample). And I used findstr to check if I get the servername return...